# possible to index singleValueExtendedProperties in MsGraph?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I have about 10 `singleValueExtendedProperties` which i am saving in Calendar Events through MsGraphApi.

```
String {D4930154-CD18-44D5-B66B-GB79C4CCC7C5} Name MyPropertyA
String {FF930134-CC00-BB56-B86B-FB99D4FFF7D1} Name MyPropertyB
```

among those, about 4 of those are highly searched. Currently the searches are kind of slow.

e.g.

```
singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'MyPropertyA' and contains(ep/value, 'searchString'))
```

Is it possible to improve the performance by having some kind of indexing enabled for those?